# Are the following spaces homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

I am comparing $[0,1) \times (0,1)$ and $(0,1) \times (0,1)$. They are pretty clearly homeomorphic intuitively (since you're effectively just adding one more verticle component to infinitely many vertical components). But I'm not too sure how to show it.

Edit: this was actually not clear nor at all intuitive

Comment: These spaces actually aren't homeomorphic. Try to find a topological property that one space has which the other one does not.

Comment: Hmmm interesting... I guess, what was wrong with my intuition, if you don't mind commenting?

Comment: Wouldn't your intuition also allow you to conclude that $[0,1)$ and $(0,1)$ are homeomorphic (just adding one point to infinitely many points)? Removing a point from the second space always leads to a disconnected space. However, if you remove point $0$ from the first then the remaining space is  still connected.

Comment: Touché, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What happens to both spaces when you remove a single point?

Comment: I'm not really seeing it. If you remove a point from each, I just get two punctured planes, both of which still feel connected to me...

Comment: Or if I remove (0,a) from the first space and any point from the second, the first space still has a trivial fundamental group, while the second one doesn't now?

Comment: That's exactly what happens!

Answer (score 0):

**Longer hint:** You can remove a point from the first space so that the remaining space is still contractible (relatively easy, not all points work!). Whatever point you remove from the second space, the result will not be contractible (you should be able to see this, but you need some tools to prove it).

**Alternatively:** Look up what a manifold with boundary is and find a theorem that states that the boundary in this case is well defined.

Comment: Okay, so if define $w=(x,y)$ the for the first space minus a point of the form $(0,a)$ I have nulhomotopy between $f(w)=w$ and $f(w)=0$ given by $F(w,t)=(1-t)w$. For the second space minus a point $(m,n)$, couldn't I just show that two paths $g,h$, where one goes over $(m,n)$ and the other under are not homotopic, thus showing that the second space isn't contractible?

Comment: @Jack, exactly, you get a space that is not simply connected (it is homotopy equivalent to a circle).

Comment: Or rather given $F(w,t)=(1-t)w+(0.5,0.5)$ since $(0,0)$ isn't in the space.

Comment: I have to admit that I did not look at the formula, but the space is star shaped.

Comment: For the second space, is it not enough to say that if there is a homotopy between $g,h$ that all points between the two functions must be mapped to for some t. So if $G(w,t)$ is the homotopy then $(m,n)=G(w,t)$ for some $t$. It's not much of a topological argument, rather using properties of continuous functions in R^n

Comment: Try to make this exact and you will see that it's not so easy.